# HOW TO IMPORT telegram.ext in python

Tags: python, c#, telegram, python-telegram-bot

from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler) . iam running this it shows like ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'telegram.ext'; 'telegram' is not a package

what should i do.

Comment: Please double check that you have installed `python-telegram-bot` to the correct python environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is pycharm or your IDE created an env for the project, and the library is installed globaly, not in the env for the project.